# Fill web view with HTML page without scrolling

Tags: android, html, view, webview, fill

I am using web view to load HTML page which as background image (827 x 1102), I trying to wrap the content within the given height and width of the webView and I don't want to scroll the content at initial stage by exploring regarding this I came to know about below lines of code

```
    mwebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mwebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

The above code is working fine on 2.2, 2.3.3 but it is adding extra space on 3.0 and higher version, you can check the attached images on different version.

I even tried by appending

```
   <head><meta name=viewport content=target-densitydpi=device-dpi/></head>
```

In html file but no luck.

[image: Motorola Xoom 3.0]
Motorla Xoom 3.0

[image: Samsung Tab 2.3.3]
Samsugn Tab 2.3.3

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you in Advance